# Split Matrix into several depending on value matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to split an nx3 matrix into submatrices in matlab. So my matrix C is of this shape

```
C =
 1     1     1
 0     0     0
 0     0     0
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 0     0     0
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
```

It either has rows of zeros or rows of ones. I want to split this matrix to only keep matrices of ones. So here for instance there's three 'groups' of ones. so I want to get

```
C1 =
 1     1     1

C2 =
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1

C3 =
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
```

However my real matrix is an n by 3, so i don't know where the ones are.

**Edit 1:**

Now, i need to split `x1` and `y1` (individual row vectors with same length as `C`) to `x(1), x(2),..` (similarly for `y` vector) based on how the matrix `C` was split

**Sample Input:**

```
x1 = (1:9)';
y1 = (2:2:18)';
```

**Desired Output:**

```
x(1)=[1], x(2)=[4 5 6]' and x(3)=[8 9]'
y(1)=[2], y(2) =[8 10 12]' and y(3)=[16 18]'
```

Comment: Completely changing the question after it has been answered is not recommended. if you think the previous problem got solved, why don't you post this question separately?

Comment: Ok I will do, I just didn't want to ask too many questions about the same problem cause people think I would be asking over and over. I will ask this separately.

Comment: Also kindly revert back your question as it was earlier to make the answers give some sense

Comment: yep thank you i think it works, I am trying to put the scatter function in the loop now but i just get a white screen....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Input:**

```
c = [1     1     1;
     0     0     0;
     0     0     0;
     1     1     1;
     1     1     1;
     1     1     1;
     0     0     0;
     1     1     1;
     1     1     1;]    

x1 = (1:9)';

y1 = (2:2:18)';
```

**Code:**

```
elementalLengthA = cellfun('length',regexp(sprintf('%i',all(C,2)),'1+','match'));
elementalStartA = regexp(sprintf('%i',all(C,2)),'1+','start');
result = cell(length(elementalLengthA),1);
x = cell(length(elementalLengthA),1);
y = cell(length(elementalLengthA),1);
for i = 1:length(elementalLengthA)
    result(i) = {C(elementalStartA(i):elementalStartA(i)+elementalLengthA(i)-1,:)};
    x(i) = {x1(elementalStartA(i):elementalStartA(i)+elementalLengthA(i)-1,:)};
    y(i) = {y1(elementalStartA(i):elementalStartA(i)+elementalLengthA(i)-1,:)};
end
```

**Output:**

```
>> cell2mat(result(1))
ans =
 1     1     1

>> cell2mat(result(2))
ans =
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1

>> cell2mat(result(3))
ans =
 1     1     1
 1     1     1

>> cell2mat(x(3))  %similarly do it for other cells to get results
ans =
 8
 9
```

Comment: Hi Sathan, thanks for you help. I was wondering now, I am using the function
`scatter(x1,y1,50,C,'filled')
poly=convhull(x1,y1);
hold on
plot(x1(poly),y1(poly))`
But in order for convhull to work specifically for each region, I need to include all those in the for loop. My x1 and y1 variables are two column vectors, and similarly I want to split them to the same length as C but they have random numbers (position of each dot). 
How do I say in the loop x1(i)= length of result(i)
Then maybe I can write my scatter in the loop as scatter(x1(i),y1(i),C(i))
Do you think thats possible?

Comment: I'm not getting your problem.. Edit your question giving example input and output @DorianKartalovski

Answer (score 1):

Use find function to the first column to find the indices of 1-elements. Then, calculate the relative distance between any two consecutive elements of the obtained vector to determine the boundary. After that, use matrix indexing to get the blocks of 1-element-matrices. Let me know if you have a better idea.

```
c=[1     1     1;
     0     0     0;
     0     0     0;
     1     1     1;
     1     1     1;
     1     1     1;
     0     0     0;
     1     1     1;
     1     1     1;]
b=c(:, 1);
find(b);
```

I will leave the rest to yourself.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, I am really new in Matlab. How would you write that for an arbitrary matrix B.
I wrote find (B(:,1)==1);